# Bot builder : How to enable my Bot within SPFx to recognize the user once connected

Tags: .net, sharepoint, botframework, spfx

I'm trying to integrate my chat Bot in the sharepoint website. What i want in that i can recognize the current user that is using my bot (for example if the user X is connected to sharepoint and says hello, the bot replies "Hi X") because i want to manage the lists in sharepoint relative to each user.

I've searched and i found a framework called SPFx for sharepoint.

Is this framework the solution ? If so how can i enable my Bot within SPFx ?
If not how can i determine the current user ? is it by authentificating before chatting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Builder : How to create a bot using OAuth 2 implicit grant flow method in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293550/bot-builder-how-to-create-a-bot-using-oauth-2-implicit-grant-flow-method-in-sh)

Answer (score 0):

SPfx is the solution.
This is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) how to start:

```
public render(): void { // <----------<<< under your render mothod you write following line:
    let currentUser=this.context.pageContext.user.displayName;
```