# Bot Builder : How to create a bot using OAuth 2 implicit grant flow method in sharepoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, botframework

I'm trying to create a bot in a sharepoint site. To do that i need to retrieve the user info using implicit flow authentification method, however i haven't found any example using .NET and all the examples are in Node.js.

Can someone show me how to do that please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of .net examples online:
https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2017/01/04/microsoft-bot-framework-transparent-authentication-with-the-webchat-control/

https://github.com/Ellerbach/SharePointBot

https://www.rickvanrousselt.com/contextual-authentication-webchat-control/

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/chat-bot-luis-sharepoint-part-one-akshay-deshmukh/

However, they are a little dated.  Just this week, Microsoft released a new integrated OAuth feature for bots.

[image]

One of the Service Providers is Sharepoint:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the AuthBot from Mr. EllerBach works and i can retrieve the userName after authentificating

Comment: @SoufienHajji can you detail how you achieved this ? I'm also facing the same problem